# Using Nuxt with Axios on Google Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, vue.js, axios, firebase-hosting, nuxt.js

Everything works fine except when deployed to Firebase hosting, the **axios** `baseURL` and/or `proxy` default to local. They seem to ignore the values set in the `nuxt.config.js` and thus result in `404`'s.

If I hardcode my URL's all API calls  work fine, but I'd like to avoid that.

What should I change in order for my Nuxt SSR API calls to work in production (firebase hosting) with my own defined `baseURL` and `proxy`, just as in development?

**nuxt.config.js**

```
axios: {
    proxy: true,
    baseURL: 'http://staging.unicorns.com',
    browserBaseURL: '/api'
},
proxy: {
    '/api': 'http://staging.unicorns.com'
},
```

e.g.

API call in development:

`GET` `http://staging.unicorns.com/api/users` `200`

API call in production (**wrong** url):

`GET` `http://unicorns-staging.firebaseapp.com/api/users` `404`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be to `proxy`. Turning it off resolved the issue.

Have since moved over to Heroku as Firebase didn't support latest node / nuxt (edge)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your .bash_profile or .profile to make you're not setting a base_url there. Also, depending on your configuration — you may need to rebuild the project on your production environment. e.g npm build

Answer (score 0):

You can add http-proxy-middleware inside your cloud functions and achieve this

*library url*

[http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware)